# Conflict with \fi in figure captions

Tags: math-mode, compiling, incompatibility, ifthenelse, definition

I have the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

% PACKAGES
% graphics packages
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% negative phantoms (\nphantom, \nhphantom, \nvphantom)
    \catcode`@=11
    \def\nvphantom{\v@true\h@false\nph@nt}
    \def\nhphantom{\v@false\h@true\nph@nt}
    \def\nphantom{\v@true\h@true\nph@nt}
    \def\nph@nt{\ifmmode\def\next{\mathpalette\nmathph@nt}\else\let\next\nmakeph@nt\fi\next}
    \def\nmakeph@nt#1{\setbox\z@\hbox{#1}\nfinph@nt}
    \def\nmathph@nt#1#2{\setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}\nfinph@nt}
    \def\nfinph@nt{\setbox\tw@\null \ifv@ \ht\tw@\ht\z@ \dp\tw@\dp\z@\fi\ifh@ \wd\tw@-\wd\z@\fi \box\tw@}
% frequently used symbols
    \renewcommand{\hbar}{h\nhphantom{h}\bar{\phantom{n}}}
```

The `negative phantoms` code does just what it says: it allows me to use `\nhphantom` (for example) to create a `\phantom` with negative width. I've then redefined `\hbar` to use a `\nhphantom` (I know there's already an `\hbar` command built into one of the mathematical symbols packages; that's beside the point.)

The following codes work just fine:

```
\begin{document}

$\hbar$

\end{document}
```

and

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig-Raman-spontaneous.pdf}}
\caption{$h$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, if I add an `$\hbar$` in the figure caption, the code doesn't compile (I'm using XeLaTeX). Looking at the compilation log, it seems the `\fi` in the definition of the negative phantoms is what's causing the problem:

[image]

Is there a way around this, preferably one that'll allow `\fi` to be used inside figure captions instead of forcing me to redefine the negative phantoms or the `\hbar` command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unrelated but don't load `graphics` and as you are using xetex don't use the pdftex option to `graphicx`  so `\usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` should be  just `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: replace `\renewcommand{\hbar}{h\nhphantom{h}\bar{\phantom{n}}}` by `\protected\def\hbar{h\nhphantom{h}\bar{\phantom{n}}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the tips. Why shouldn’t I use `graphics` and the `pdftex` option?

Comment: `graphics` is loaded by `graphicx` so explicitly loading it is just harmless but does nothing useful, as you are not using `pdftex` then specifying `[pdftex]` is just wrong, Nothing would work at all if it was activated, you just got lucky that via an accidental code path `graphics` defaulted to `xetex` and then the unused `pdftex` option wasn't flagged as an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the reason for redefining `\hbar`, as the standard definition yields a better result. In the [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpBW2.png) you see on the left your redefined `\hbar` and on the right the standard.

Comment: @egreg Font reasons. The font I'm using doesn't have a symbol for the reduced Planck constant, so it uses the default font for it, which looks awful in the middle of a wall of text which is in a different font.

Comment: Neither has the Computer Modern font. It also uses a displaced bar accent over the h.

Comment: OK, but if I call the default `\hbar` command while using another font it uses Computer Modern for the *h* for some reason, hence the redefinition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\hbar}{h\nhphantom{h}\bar{\phantom{n}}}` instead of `\renewcommand`

See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) for further information on why.

Comment: Thanks, will try this as soon as I get home. I didn’t understand everything in that link, but I think I get the basics. :)

Comment: @Rain Don't worry - I haven't fully understood the whole robust/fragile stuff either. It's sufficient to know that it exists and how to fix it :)

Comment: OK, just tried this and it works. It's also the answer which most concisely solves my problem and the one that most directly addresses it, so I've accepted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using negative phantoms is not the best way to deal with the problem; it's simpler to typeset the bar in a zero width box (I also added a slight backing up, which you can tailor to your needs).

The main issue is that `\hbar` should be made robust.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

% PACKAGES
% graphics packages
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\hbar}{{%
  \mathrlap{\mspace{-1mu}\bar{\phantom{x}}}h%
}}
\MakeRobust{\hbar}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption{$\hbar$}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted because this indeed looks better than my definition. Thanks!